# UPDATE SQL Not Working

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-update, vb.net-2010

This is my SQL statement:

```
query = "Update(tbl_shifts) SET StartTime=" & starttime & ", Endtime =" & endtime & ", TotalHours =" & totalhours & ", TotalPay=" & pay & ", Completed =" & True & "WHERE ShiftDate=" & DateTime.Today And "EmployeeName =" & EmployeeLogin.usersname
```

Upon the click of the button, it is supposed to add the variables (starttime, endtime, totalhours, pay) and tick the yes/no '`Completed`' field into the row of `tbl_shifts` where the entry in the column '`EmployeeName`' matches the global variable '`EmployeeLogin.usersname`' and the entry in the column `ShiftDate` (which is currently stored as `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS`) matches `DateTime.Today` (which is only `DD/MM/YYYY` (I think)). What do I do to make my sql work as intended?

Comment: What is your problem? What is the intended behavior? Also *please* read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection) question and its answers.

Comment: you need an space before WHERE

Comment: Also: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: I'm using access. I need the variables detailed above to be inserted into the blank fields in tblwhere EmployeeName = employeelogin.usersname and ShiftDate = datetime.today. Although the entries into ShiftDate are DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS whereas Datetime.today is only DD/MM/YYYY so i need to know how to: 1) make the sql work and 2) how to match a DD/MM/YYYY value to a DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS value

Answer (score 0):

There are a few typo's in your query

This:

```
query = "Update(tbl_shifts) SET StartTime=" & starttime & ", Endtime =" & endtime & ", TotalHours =" & totalhours & ", TotalPay=" & pay & ", Completed =" & True & "WHERE ShiftDate=" & DateTime.Today And "EmployeeName =" & EmployeeLogin.usersname
```

should be:

```
query = "Update tbl_shifts SET StartTime=" & starttime & ", Endtime =" & endtime & ", TotalHours =" & totalhours & ", TotalPay=" & pay & ", Completed =" & True &  " WHERE ShiftDate=" & DateTime.Today & " And EmployeeName =" & EmployeeLogin.usersname
```

So

- Update tbl_shifts
- a space key before WHERE
- move the double quote before " And EmployeeName